# On leave / On a leave

Tags: nouns

I know one should say: "I was on leave" and not "I was on a leave".

Can you explain why?

How should you say: "He took a leave" or "He took leave">

Thanks.

Comment: You can certainly say "took *a* two-month leave", or "was given an unpaid leave for the summer", so I think the issue boils down to [*on leave* as a fixed phrase](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-leave), rather than *leave* as a noun.

Comment: @Dan Bron Though you carefully avoid 'took a leave'. I think eligibility for count and/or non-count usage is idiosyncratic and in flux.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't avoid it: I thought it implied by my first example? However, I would read "took a leave" as a deletion of "took a leave [of absence]" more strongly in that case that in the others I described. As I said, I think the issue here is more the two word phrase "on leave" (which like most fixed phrases, breaks under even minor modifications), not the count or mass status of the single-word noun "leave".

Comment: @Dan Bron I would consider 'took a leave' as very much less idiomatic (at least in the UK) than 'took a two-month leave'. 'Padding' can make a great difference to how acceptable something sounds (??'Sad, he walked out of the room.' / 'Sad at the news of his best friend's arrest, he walked out of the room.' It's not just grammaticality and sensible interpretation that determine acceptability.

Comment: So, to say "I was on a leave", is okay?

Comment: @NadavB No, not ok. What I'm trying to get across is "on leave", as a two word phrase is *fixed*, like an idiom is fixed, and you should not try to make any adjustments to it.

Answer (score -1):

[Leave is an uncountable noun.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leave)

This means you never use an indefinite article or a numeric specifier. Other mass nouns include "air" or "grass". You say:

> I breathed air

not "I breathed an air", and

> I sat on grass

not "I sat on a grass".

Comment: The very first comment was 'You can certainly say "took a two-month leave" '. Wiktionary allows count and non-count usages.

Comment: In Google Books: ["All she had was a grainy snapshot of Eve taken on the farm on one leave."](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Girl_on_the_Beach/VB2KAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on+one+leave%22&pg=PT192&printsec=frontcover), ["On one leave I decided to raid the pantry and took a tin of treacle back.'](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Metamorphosis/Z9kdAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on+one+leave%22&pg=PA33&printsec=frontcover)